# bimolecular reaction master equation

Tags: physical-chemistry, stochastic-processes

I was wondering how to write down the deterministic rate equation for a bimolecular reaction with similar particles.

e.g.

$A \rightarrow^{k_+} B +B$
and $B +B \rightarrow^{k_-} A$

now the rate equations for the above reactions are,

$\frac{dA}{dt}= - k_+ A + k_- B^2$

$\frac{dB}{dt}= 2 k_+ A - 2 k_- B^2$

Now I have included a factor of 2 in the second equation to conserve $A + \frac{B}{2}$.

But I dont understand the reason for this factor of 2 in the second equation.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is about the factors of $2$ in the expression for $dB \over dt$.

The first term, $2k_+A$, has a factor of $2$ because for every reaction of an $A$ molecule two $B$ molecules are formed.

The second term, $-2k_- B^2$ has a factor of $2$ because in the reaction of $B$ with $B$ to form $A$ two $B$ molecules are lost.

Hope this helps.